# Higher Order Components(HOC)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a project that I'm working on for the sake of understanding react routing. I have several components, but I just want to focus on two, one component increases the number of coins (buy) and the other decreases the coins (sell). I am having trouble understanding how a higher order component would help me display data from both components. If there is an alternative way of going about this, that would be great. Here's are two of the components.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Mine extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        coins: 0,
        answer: ""
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({coins: this.state.coins + 1})
    console.log("Your Answer: " + this.state.answer + " and coins: " + this.state.coins);
}
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.answer);
}
render() {
    const {answer} = this.state;
    const isEnabled = answer.length > 0;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Mine Shinto Coins</h1>
            <p>Here you can Mine shinto Coins by being the first to solve the algorithom.</p>
            <p>What is the 7th Fibonacci sequence Number?</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name = "answer" onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Mine" disabled = {!isEnabled}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
} 
export default Mine
```

I will work on the answers letter, The other component is the same thing , just decrease the coins.

Comment: If your state structure and method implementations are more or less alike, then you can move it to an HOC. In this case, you do not need an HOC as such, you could make this component re-usable to handle both the cases using a prop which gives you the type (`increment` or `decrement`)

Comment: In adding to @varunagarwal you can pass onChange() callback to your child component, if it's the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
function withCoinDeal(Component, howChange) {  
  return class extends React.Component {
    state = {
      coins: 0
    }
    handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    componentDidMount() {
      DataSource.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      DataSource.removeChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    }
    handleChange() {
      this.setState({
        coins: howChange(DataSource, this.props)
      });
    }
    render() {
      return <Component coins={this.state.coins} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

Above example shows how a HOC suit for this situation, but not for your case.